# What's the difference in using the paragraph tag and simply typing in the text?

Tags: html

So, I have a checkbox followed by some text.

```
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
        </label>
```

It works fine. However, when I put the text in a paragraph tag, it puts the text on the next line. This made me wonder, other than formatting purposes and what not, is it highly inadvisable to use text without any tags? Why or why not? Is the usage of tagless text simply against etiquette?

Comment: did you google it? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp

Comment: Paragraphs are block elements by default. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: Just note that `<p>` elements inside `<label>` elements is invalid HTML, so you should not do it.

Answer (score 0):

By “tagless text”, you seem to refer to text content and text-level markup (like `label` and `input`) that is not wrapped in a block-level container like `p` or `div`. Such text has always been valid in HTML, though HTML 2, HTML 4, and XHTML 1.0 all have a “strict” version where such text (which might be called “loose text”) is not allowed e.g. directly inside the `body` element or directly inside a `form` element. In [HTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_toc.html), the “strict” version was characterized as “more structurally rigid”. HTML 4 is silent about the reasons for the rule, and in HTML 4, the “strict” version of the language is primarily a “purified” version that mostly lacks presentational markup (markup used only for achieving specific visual appearance, like the `font` element)—this really has nothing to do with disallowing “loose text”, but the two things were bundled together.

The rule that disallows “loose that” does not have any tangible benefits, and it has probably caused more confusion (when people try to validate HTML against a “strict” specification) than any good. In HTML5, which is work in progress but widely regarded as becoming the de facto standard for HTML, has no such rule. It has a complicated “paragraph” concept that does *not* coincide with the `p` element concept *or* with the traditional typographic paragraph concept. Anyway, it explicitly says that text need not be wrapped in a `p` element even if it is structurally a “paragraph” (in HTML5 sense). It also describes that a `p` element *can* be used to wrap a part of a form, like an input field and its label.

So it’s rather confusing. The bottom line is that a `p` element is a block element that may contain text and text-level markup only (and browsers actually enforce this) and that has default top and bottom margin, corresponding to about one empty line or a little less. So in addition to causing its content to start on a new line (and the subsequent content to start on a fresh line), `p` also causes some vertical spacing. In contrast, the `div` element behaves similarly but without the margins (vertical spacing).

The practical conclusion is that the `p` element can be used to group text if the vertical margins are desired. If they are not desired but line breaks are, `div` is suitable. And if you don’t want even line breaks (though a form field and its label usually work best when they appear on a line of their own), don’t use any particular markup.

Comment: Naaah. You've completely missed the point and overcomplicated everything.

Answer (score -2):

Novadays, the purpose of the tags is to define semantic meaning and have less to do with the presentation (how the text looks to the user, new lines, etc). This is rather the purpose of CSS, the cascading style sheets.

By using the `<p>` tag, you are telling web crawlers and other users that the data is indeed, the paragraph, a logically complete piece of text.

> A paragraph (from the Greek paragraphos, "to write beside" or "written
>   beside") is a self-contained unit of a discourse in writing dealing
>   with a particular point or idea. A paragraph consists of one or more
>   sentences.[1][2] Though not required by the syntax of any language,
>   paragraphs are usually an expected part of formal writing, used to
>   organize longer prose.

Source: Wikipedia

Comment: The answer does not cite any HTML specification or draft and presents just an opinion of what “paragraphs” are and calls it “semantic”. There is no evidence of any crawler or other user agent paying any attention to some “paragraph semantics”.